# Intellij IDEA: How to navigate between tabs of debug tool window using the keyboard?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

[image]

Is there any possibility to navigate between these tabs using the keyboard?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> shortcuts navigate through the nested tabs Console/Debugger in the case shown above.

Answer (score 7):

I found the [discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205972224-Shortcuts-for-navigating-between-nested-tabs-in-debug-tool-and-test-tool-windows) related to my question. It seems that it was not designed for keyboard:

> Actually it's designed for mouse/trackpad and there is no way to
>   switch from cell to cell.

And there is an [issue IDEA-164210](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164210) about that in JetBrains tracker.

Answer (score 3):

Open keymap setting, search "tab" and find

"Window -> Active Tool Window -> Show List of Tabs"

The default keymap is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>, actually it's a mistake for duplicate with "Next Method". So I just replace it by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>.

[image: Debug base dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to apply a keyboard shortcut to tabs navigation in PyCharm, which should work with Intellij IDEA as well.

- Opened preferences, under "keymap"
- Filtered by "tab"
- Under "Window", "Editor tabs", "Select Next Tab" and "Select Previous Tab".

Comment: Select Next Tab/Previous Tab shortcuts allow to navigate between Console/Debugger tabs in the example above, but not between upper-level tabs.

Comment: For me on the mac it seems to work. As said in my answer above you even select "Editor tabs" under "keymap", so apparently it should work in the editor itself as well.